# Merge Sort implementation in Java

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

Can you check my merge sort implementation?  From all of my testing it seems like it works, but I just wanted to make sure I am doing it as good as possible, and it couldn't be optimized any further.

```
private static void merge(int[] c,int[] a, int[] b){
    int i = 0;//index for a
    int j = 0;//index for b
    for(int k = 0; k < c.length; k++){
        //check a[] edge case
        if(i >= a.length){
            c[k] = b[j];
            j++;
        }else if(j >= b.length){
            c[k] = a[i];
            i++;
        }else if(a[i] < b[j]) {
            c[k] = a[i];
            i++;            
        } else {
            c[k] = b[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}

public static void mergeSort(int[] A){
    if(A.length > 1){
        int pivot = A.length / 2;
        int[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, 0, pivot);
        int[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, pivot,A.length);
        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);
        merge(A,left,right);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Mostly LGTM, with the following objections.

- **Names**. Avoid which require a comment to be understood. I'd have no problem with `int ax;` because it clearly conveys the goal of being an index of a.
- **Conditionals**.
- You can statically prove that `i > a.length` is not possible. If by any chance it happens, it means that something really weird is going on. A good cause to raise an exception. Bottomline is, separate a `==` test from `>` one.
- Once one of the ranges is exhausted, there's no need to test it again and again. Normally one would break a main loop and copy the remaining data separately

along the lines of:

```
while (A has data) and (B has data)
    calculate what to copy
    copy it to C

while (A has data)
    copy A to C

while (B has data)
    copy B to C
```

- **Types**. The methods cry to be generic. If you didn't cover generics yet, disregard the objection.

Answer (score 0):

This is new implementation.  It is a little bit longer, but I think that it is easier to read.

```
private static <T extends Comparable<T>>void merge(T[] sorted,T[] left,T[] right){
    int leftIndex = 0;
    int rightIndex = 0;
    int sortedIndex = 0;
    //while left and right both have data
    while(leftIndex < left.length  && rightIndex < right.length){
        if(left[leftIndex].compareTo(right[rightIndex]) < 0) {
            sorted[sortedIndex] = left[leftIndex];
            leftIndex++;            
        } else {
            sorted[sortedIndex] = right[rightIndex];
            rightIndex++;
        }
        sortedIndex++;
    }

    //while left has data
    while(leftIndex < left.length){
        sorted[sortedIndex] = left[leftIndex];
        leftIndex++;
        sortedIndex++;
    }
    //while right has data
    while(rightIndex < right.length){
        sorted[sortedIndex] = right[rightIndex];
        rightIndex++;
        sortedIndex++;
    }
}

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void mergeSort(T[] A){
    if(A.length > 1){
        int pivot = A.length / 2;
        T[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, 0, pivot);
        T[] right = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, pivot,A.length);
        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);
        merge(A,left,right);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also post follow up questions. See the help center.

Answer (score 0):

An updated version (a follow-up question would look better indeed) is very close to be very good. However notice that last two loops are identical. It is a good indication that they represent an important algorithm which shall be recognized and factored out. In this case, it is `copy()`.

Another deficiency worth mentioning is that the code is restricted to arrays. In reality the only thing `merge` needs is an ability to access `next` element. Sounds like `merge` arguments want to be iterators.